# Enabling OAuth 2.0 authentication for REST services using WSO2 Identity Server as Authorization server

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server for the first time and we are evaluating WSO2 IS to 
enable OAuth 2.0 authentication for the REST services. I have 2 specific questions in this regard:

1. Where may i find an sample application where the client application
   integration with WSO2 IS?
2. Is there any documentation for the APIs to
   be used to communicate with WSO2 IS?
3. Does WSO2 IS support integration via REST call?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just trying to do the same exact thing. The only resource i've found so far that points in the right direction is [this article](http://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/apply-oauth2-0-base-security-for-rest-endpoint-with-wso2esb-4-6-0-and-wso2is-4-1-1-alpha/).
Seems that you need to use wso2esb in front of your REST API to intercept all incoming calls. The ESB needs to be configured with a message handler responsible for authorizing and authenticating each request with the IS. Once the request is autenticated its passed on to the API.
If you advance on this issue please leave your findings!

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Securing+REST+APIs

This shows how to use an ESB handler to secure a particular REST endpoint. In that case your API needs to be fronted by WSO2 ESB.

Comment: I hate that they offer a SOAP solution to a REST question.